# Python - Read Columns from CSV with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV File and I want to separate Columns to Lists in Python (with Pandas).

I already done this before with other CSVs, and nothing gone wrong.

This is the code i'm using:

```
from pandas import *

data = read_csv("newCSV Report.csv")

computer = data['Computer Name'].tolist()
user        = data['Computer Current User'].tolist()

print(computer)
print(user)
```

And this is my CSV File: (I covered the Rows for privacy)

[image]

Finally, this is the error I get if i run the code:

[image]

How I can solve this?

EDIT that might help to solve:
If I print *data* before creating the two lists, that's the result:
[image]

So Python recognizes only 1 Column instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try add `sep = "\t"` to data:

```
data = pd.read_csv("newCSV Report.csv", sep = "\t")
```

Your previous error was from invalid key, when you imported csv file You didn't have 2 separate columns cause of default setting sep=",".
You was searching `['Computer Name']` and `['Computer Current User']` but there was just `['Computer Name\tComputer Current User']`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened with me. Try this once:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("newCSV Report.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

computer = data['Computer Name'].tolist()
user        = data['Computer Current User'].tolist()

print(computer)
print(user)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still same error

Comment: Not sure if it matters but try changing the 'Computer Name' to 'ComputerName' without spaces. Also, the 'ComputerCurrentUser'

Comment: Doesn't work either. I updated the post by the way